# Using ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers() results in Server Error

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I'm using Google Apps Script in Google Sheets.
I have a problem with this function:

```
var projectTriggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
```

From 20.06.18 this function stopped working, and give the error (from Czech):

> Sorry, there was a server error. Wait for a moment, then try again.

Maybe Google launched a new function? But this function is very important for my scripts. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What error are you getting ?

Comment: I have it in Czech, but is something like 
Sorry, there was a server error. Wait for a moment, then try again.

Comment: Are the only triggers in the relevant documents from your account? You'll have to ask your coworkers to check if they have triggers since you cannot view that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this seems to be affecting plenty of people right now.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=getProjectTriggers()

So, this is a known issue - I hope google will fix soon.  You might help by adding your star ... for those who don't know select one (or all related) issue on the list; when you open you will see a star outline. Select it so it goes yellow as per diagram below:

[image: Google issue tracker: Scripts - Error when request triggers by getProjectTriggers and getUserTriggers]

Comment: Updates to the issue tracker:  users are saying that this is now fixed (no official comment from google at this time though)

Answer (score -2):

Create script through spreadsheet or document.